# Is the Fourier Transform of a quantum field well-defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, quantum-field-theory

Let there be a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and let $\hat\phi(t,\vec{x})$ be a bounded linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R},\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. There exists a Hilber basis $\{|n\rangle\}_{n=0}^\infty$ that allows me to write
$$\hat\phi(t,\vec{x}) = \sum_n\sum_m\phi^n_m(t,\vec{x})\,|n\rangle\langle m|,$$
and these real-valued functions are at least well-behaved enough to have a Fourier Transform, by hypothesis.

I am told in Quantum Field theory that I can define the Fourier Transform of $\hat\phi(t,\vec{x})$, which I will call $\hat{\tilde{\phi}}(t,\vec{p})$, by doing

$$\hat\phi(t,\vec{x}) = \sum_{n,m}\phi^n_m(t,\vec{x})\,|n\rangle\langle m| = \sum_{n,m}\left(\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\tilde\phi{}^n_m(t,\vec{p})\,\mathrm{d}^3p\right)|n\rangle\langle m| = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\underbrace{\sum_{n,m}\tilde\phi{}^n_m(t,\vec{p})\,|n\rangle\langle m|}_{\hat{\tilde\phi}(t,\vec{p})}\,\mathrm{d}^3p.$$

Is this actually rigorous? Does the expression in components for $\hat{\tilde\phi}(t,\vec{p})$ always converge by virtue of some theorem (Paserval's, Riezs' or some other one, I tried but didn't succeed) or is this definition only valid for a subclass of all possible field operators?

Comment: If you already know that the $\phi$ are well-behaved enough to have a Fourier transform, I do not see what is your problem? In what sense do you take the Fourier transform? $L^1$, $L^2$ or Tempered distributions?

Comment: $L^2$ distributions, @LL3.14

Comment: Remark: In math, one usually takes the reverse notation: $^$ indicates the Fourier transform and $\bar{}$ the conjugation.

Comment: By the ^ hat I just mean "operator". By the tilde ~ I mean FT. For conjugation, we use either the bar or the star, but I used none. Sorry for the confusion :( @LL3.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you are looking at the special case of the $L^2$ theory Fourier transform, this is very compatible with Hilbert-Schmidt operators. The time variable plays no role in this question so I drop it. One can write an $x$ dependent Hilbert-Schmidt operator in the form (see e.g. Simon, *Trace Ideals and their Applications*, Th. 1.4)
$$
\Phi(x) = \sum_{n} \phi_n(x)\,|\varphi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|
$$
where $\{\varphi_n\}$ and $\{\psi_n\}$ are two orthonormal sets. Then the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of the operator for every fixed $x\in\Bbb R^3$ is just
$$
\|\Phi(x)\|_2 = {\rm Tr}(\Phi(x)^*\Phi(x))^{1/2} = \left(\sum_{n} |\phi_n(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
In the case of a finite rank operator, the family $\{\psi_n\}$ is finite and this is just the classical finite dimensional Euclidian norm and these finite rank operators from a dense subset of general Hilbert-Schmidt operators.

Now we want to take the Fourier transform. One can directly use the classical theory of $L^2$ Fourier transform, and by the Parceval inequality, one gets
$$
\sum_n \int_{\Bbb R^3} |\psi_n(x)|^2\,\mathrm dx = \|\|\Phi(x)\|_2\|_{L^2_x}^2
\\
= \|\|\mathcal F_x\Phi(x)\|_2\|_{L^2_x}^2 =  \int_{\Bbb R^3}  \sum_n|\mathcal F_x\psi_n(x)|^2\,\mathrm dx
$$
where the sum and integrals can be exchanged without any problem as a property of the Lebesgue integral of positive functions.

In particular, the operator
$$
\mathcal F\Phi(p) = \sum_n \mathcal F\phi_n(p)\,|\varphi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|
$$
is a $L^2$ function of $p$ with value to Hilbert-Schmidt operators (i.e. it is in the space $L^2(\Bbb R^3, \mathrm{HS})$) and as such is in particular defined for almost every $p\in\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your answer. I will leave the bounty open just in case anyone wants to comment anything else, but then I will give it to you, of course.

Comment: One question, shouldn't the Pacerval identity yield
$\|\|\Phi(x)\|_2\|_{L^2_x}^2
= \|F_x\|\mathcal\Phi(x)\|_2\|_{L^2_x}^2$ instead of that?

Comment: No, think to what happens in the finite dimensional case. In, term of scalar product, if $f$ and $g$ are vector valued functions, you have
$$
∫ \bar{f} · g = ∫ \overline{\mathcal F f} · \mathcal F g
$$
so
$$
∫ |f|^2 = ∫ |\mathcal F f|^2
$$
where $|\cdot |$ is the Euclidian norm of your vectors (which here is replaced by the HS norm $\|\cdot\|_2$).